# How to enable modstatus into apache?

Tags: apache2

I discovered for first time the module "status" for Apache2.

Could you point me to which file modify to load the module and in which file is the mod_status config defined, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration file is located at `/etc/apache2/mods-available/status.conf` and typically requires an edit before access is allowed, once the module is enabled.

Keep a copy of the original file before editing. This example uses my configuration control methods, others do whatever works for them:

```
doug@DOUG-64:~$ cd ~/config/etc/apache2/mods-available
doug@DOUG-64:~/config/etc/apache2/mods-available$ cp /etc/apache2/mods-available/status.conf ./
doug@DOUG-64:~/config/etc/apache2/mods-available$ cp status.conf status.conf.16.04.original
doug@DOUG-64:~/config/etc/apache2/mods-available$ nano status.conf
doug@DOUG-64:~/config/etc/apache2/mods-available$ cp status.conf status.conf.doug
doug@DOUG-64:~/config/etc/apache2/mods-available$ sudo cp status.conf /etc/apache2/mods-available/status.conf
doug@DOUG-64:~/config/etc/apache2/mods-available$ sudo a2enmod status
doug@DOUG-64:~/config/etc/apache2/mods-available$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

For the edit, I allowed access from my LAN only:

```
doug@DOUG-64:~/config/etc/apache2/mods-available$ diff status.conf.16.04.original status.conf
9c9
<               #Require ip 192.0.2.0/24
---
>               Require ip 192.168.111.0/24
```

And now I can access the status page via `http://192.168.111.1/server-status`.

Comment: +1 There are `Require local` by default. Sure edit needed to allow LAN. Reference for require statement https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

Answer (score 1):

Config is placed there: `/etc/apache2/mods-available/status.conf` as well as other modules configs.
To enable module run `sudo a2enmod status`
To disable `sudo a2dismod status`
Then reload apache: `systemctl restart apache2`

Comment: The file requires and edit to work properly.